# Rails - Injected a snippet of HTML in any page when some parameter is met?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app I have projects.

Whenever a project_id is present in the PARAMS I would like to inject the following:

```
<script>
project_id = 123123;
</script>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this without having to touch multiple views/pages ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the layout, that way it can show up on all your pages:

```
# application.html.erb
...
<% if !params[:project_id].blank? %>
  <script>
    project_id = <%= params[:project_id] %>;
  </script>
<% end %>
...
```

Better yet, if you have a common _javascript partial that gets loaded in all of your layouts, put your code in that partial.